# Pop-up, when data already saved

Tags: javascript, jsf, popup

I have a problem with the pop-up:

> This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.

I am using JavaServer Faces and JavaScript, and after navigating away (and saving every data that I need) if on the next page I click on any button, I see the pop-up. So it doesn't even appear on the page when the data was given, but on the next one, where I have just a few buttons to select the next action.

Does any easy way exist, to find out which part of the data is not saved?

Comment: I was modifying parts of the data, and after moving away the page and returning to the page again, everything shows up again, but the pop-up still comes up every time.

Comment: Hi, please read [ask] and improve your question...